# How do I grab the nth value from this SimpleXMLObject in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a SimpleXMLElement and would like to check if a particular element has a non-blank value before looping through it utilizing a foreach loop. Here is my SimpleXMLObject

Say this is contained in $myXMLElement

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [f] => Array ( [0] => Marcus [1] => Smith [2] => Brown University [3] => 1243123200000 [4] => Masters [5] => TestValue [6] => TestValue2 [7] => 4 [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 16 ) ) [9] => 0 ) [update_id] => 1325795135203 )
```

Within the array is a value of

```
[3] => 1243123200000
```

This is what I would like to check this parameter and determine that it is not NULL. If I wanted to grab it as a String what would be the way to do this.

I was hoping for something like (string)$myXMLElement[3] but that does not appear to be correct syntax for what I am trying.

Comment: I already thought that with your last question, it would be better that you share more of your code, so it's more clear what you actually need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array notation, but since the array is part of the node `f` you have to access it like this:

```
$val = $xmlObj->f[3];

if (empty($val)) {
    // its empty
}
```

On an unrelated note, since the 8th element in that array is itself a SimpleXML object, you would access its values like this:

```
$val = $xmlObj->f[8]->update_id;
```

In these cases, its just a mix of object access and array access notation.

To get the attributes from the 8th element, you can also use array notation:

```
$id = $xmlObj->f[8]['id']; // get "id" attribute
```

The page on [Basic SimpleXML Usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) has some very helpful examples showing how to access different elements from a SimpleXML object.  Example #5 show how to [access attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5081).

Comment: In Field 8 how do I get the ID in the @attributes array?

[8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 16 ) )

Comment: @JosephU. I just updated the answer with an example on getting attributes.